# Struggling to build multi dimensional arrays with unique ids

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework, backbone.js, unique

Lets say I have some db rows that looks something like this:

```
group    version  tool         info
group_a  m        screwdriver  for screwing things
group_a  m        hammer       for hitting things
group_a  l        screwdriver  for screwing things
group_a  xl       screwdriver  for screwing things
group_b  m        screwdriver  for screwing things
group_b  m        hammer       for hitting things
group_b  m        wrench       for wrenching things
group_b  l        screwdriver  for screwing things
group_b  xl       wrench       for wrenching things
```

and from that I want to create and array that looks something like this:

```
array(
    array( 'id' => 'group_a',
        array( 'id' => 'm',
            array( 'id' => 'screwdriver',
                'info' => 'for screwing things'
            ),
            array( 'id' => 'hammer',
                'info' => 'for hitting things'
            ),
        ),
        array( 'id' => 'l',
            array( 'id' => 'screwdriver',
                'info' => 'for screwing things'
            ),
        ),
        array( 'id' => 'xl',
            array( 'id' => 'screwdriver',
                'info' => 'for screwing things'
            ),
        )
    array( 'id' => 'group_b',
        array()
    )
    ~~~~~~~ etc ~~~~~~~
);
```

For a bit of context I'm passing this as JSON from Zend to BackboneJS that will then consume these arrays into a Group Collection, which contains n number of Version Collections which contains n number of Tool Models.

Any help greatly received, happy to clarify any points.

Cheers.

Comment: I'm sorry, so what exactly is the problem?  Your title says unique ids but you don't mention that in your question...

Answer (score 0):

I dont really like this as it will throw notices like crazy.  But the end result would be something like this:

```
$array = array();
while($row = fetch($query) {
  $array['id'][$row['group']]['id'][$row['version']]['id'] = $row['tool'];
  $array['id'][$row['group']]['id'][$row['version']]['info'] = $row['info'];
}
```

I would make it more elegant with issets, and checks to prevent things from being overwrote and appended to instead.

I would probably use the actual ID as a key instead of the word to help with the uniqueness as well.

Anyway this should help you get thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Transform your data into a three dimensional temporary array.

```
$temparray=array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $temparray[$row['group']][$row['version']][$row['tool']]=$row['info'];
}
```

This temporary array will look similar to what you're trying to achieve, but not quite:

```
Array
(
    [group_a] => Array(
            [m] => Array(
                    [screwdriver] => for screwing things
                    [hammer] => for hitting things
                )
            [l] => Array(
                    [screwdriver] => for screwing things
                )
            [xl] => Array(
                    [screwdriver] => for screwing things
                )
    )
    [group_b] => Array(
            [m] => Array(
                    [screwdriver] => for screwing things
                    [hammer] => for hitting things
                    [wrench] => for wrenching things
                )
            [l] => Array(
                    [screwdriver] => for screwing things
                )
            [xl] => Array(
                    [wrench] => for wrenching things
                )
    )
)
```

Now either that's enough for your needs or you have to reproduce the exact structure you'vw shown. In the latter case, just loop over that temporary array to acheive your goal:

```
foreach ($temparray as $groupid=>$groupdata) {
  $grouparray=array('id'=>$groupid);
  foreach ($groupdata as $versionid=>$versiondata) {
    $versionarray=array('id'=>$versionid);
    foreach ($versiondata as $toolid=>$tooldata) {
      $toolarray=array('id'=>$infoid,'info'=>$tooldata);
      $versionarray[]=$toolarray;
    }
    $grouparray[]=$versionarray;
  }
  $targetarray[]=$grouparray;
}
```

And you're done :)

BTW, arrays that have 'id',0,1,2,... as index are a bit awkward. I don't know BackboneJS, but any script that uses such a format (rather than what the temptable looks like) look quite suspicious to me.